# What is the word pronounced at 0:48 in this video?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-meaning, learning

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIyy7x4XqEc), there is a word that I try manage to guess (I'm french), but in vain.

At 0:47, he says:
"there is this **X** that all software developers are the same."
What is **X**?

I understand that the meaning would be "rumor" but I'm curious about what it is.

Anybody knows?

Comment: You might want to check out the english language learner's stack exchange for this kind of question in the future. The word used here is "thought" (as a noun, not a past tense verb).

Comment: @pavja2 Oh yes, you're right for the wrong place of this question. Why not transform your comment in an answer so that I can validate it. Thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recognising ordinary words in normal English speech

Comment: _Why not transform your comment in[to] an answer so that I can validate it._ Because validating an answer looks like it's validating the suitability of the question, perhaps?

Comment: @Edwin No, because a question not validated stays into the list of "unanswered". And since my question doesn't fit this stackexchange theme, and since there was an answer as first comment, it would be best to close it by validating some answer into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word used here is "thought" (as a noun, not a past tense verb).

Comment: However, why do we listen to the letter "R" in the pronounced word? In "thought" there isn't the sound "rrr". It really seems to say "trrrrought", a kind of word that looks like this.

Comment: Generally there is not, in this case the speaker is just enunciating the "th" sound somewhat aggressively and it comes out sounding a bit like an 
"rr", perhaps as a result of just coming out of the awkward mouth mouth movements demanded in going from the "ss" to the "th" sound.

Answer (score 1):

There is this "**thought**" that all software developers are the same.